# how can I pass on a post data from one view to another through a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, scope

I want to load a new page with the hidden id from a table row as a post data when I click on the `view` `<td>`.
This is the code from Admin/contracts:

```
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($data as $row) {
      $id = $row->_id;
      ++$count;
     echo "<tr>
         "<input name='contract_id' id='contract_id' value='$id' hidden/>".
         "<td class=\"id_td td_content\">".$count."</td>".
         "<td class='serial_td td_content'>".$row->_id."</td>".
         "<td class='organisation_td td_content'>".$row->organisation."</td>".
         "<td class='contract_td td_content'>".$row->title."</td>".
         "<td class='lot_no_td td_content'>".$row->serial_no."</td>".
         "<td class='pub_date_td td_content'>".substr($row->pub_date, 0, 10)."</td>".
         "<td class='view_td'><a href='".site_url('Admin/contract_detail')."'>view</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
   }
```

This is the code from the Admin controller:

```
    public function contract_detail(){
     $id = $this->input->post('contract_id');
     $result['id'] = $id;
     $this->load->view('admin/contract_detail', $result);
   }
```

And the code in the admin/contract_detail view:

```
    <?php
     echo "id = ". $id;
    ?>
```

The problem is `$id` outputs nothing when echoed.
I need help please;

Comment: between quote, it will not work. try like for your other variable ( ...".$id."... )

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you redirect user to contract_detail vie anchor element 
if you want to pass the id to the contract_detail  page you have to sent it as form not link

For example

change you foreach to the following

```
 foreach ($data as $row) {
  $id = $row->_id;
  ++$count;
 echo "<tr><form action='".site_url('Admin/contract_detail')."' method='post'>
     "<input name='contract_id' id='contract_id' value='$id' hidden/>".
     "<td class=\"id_td td_content\">".$count."</td>".
     "<td class='serial_td td_content'>".$row->_id."</td>".
     "<td class='organisation_td td_content'>".$row->organisation."</td>".
     "<td class='contract_td td_content'>".$row->title."</td>".
     "<td class='lot_no_td td_content'>".$row->serial_no."</td>".
     "<td class='pub_date_td td_content'>".substr($row->pub_date, 0, 10)."</td>".
     "<td class='view_td'><button type='submit'>view</button></td>";
 echo "</form></tr>";
```

}

Comment: i did exactly that and still `$this->input->post('contract_id')` outputs nothing in the `contract_detail` page

Answer (score 0):

```
"<input name='contract_id' id='contract_id' value='".$id."' hidden/>".
```

Please try this line of code. I hope this helps.